# Micro SD Card as Arduino "main memory"

Tags: memory, arduino, sd-card

I would like to know if it is possible to store font code in a Micro SD card and then, afterwards, access this code to run the routines.

I'm doing some stuff with Arduino nano and due to the amount of sensors and components, I'm having problems with memory. It is causing an instability that might affect things to work properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Arduino can only run code from its program memory.

Comment: Reading an SD Card itself requires quite a lot of valuable RAM - memory. Font data is typically best stored in Flash memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best suggestion that I can give you, is switch to an Arduino Mega, or an Arduino Due.

If you are not open to that solution, then things are going to be rough.

What you will need to do, is write a bootloader, which is able to read from the memory card and change the flash contents of your Atmega.

What this essentially means is that you have to write an OS level program for your Arduino Bootloader, and use the memory card like a hard-disk and the rest of your Arduino flash as the program RAM.

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Hi Nitro! Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, I'm not open to that change due to my wearable dimensions.

Thanks for your suggestion, any help is appreciated since I have no idea what to do. 

I tried to optimize the code and reduced the usage percentage in 3%. It might be the best way.

Comment: I do not see that you have problems loading arduino program memory the standard way. "Instability" is rather a RAM problem, so you should differentiate between the two types of memory: RAM for Variables, FLASH for Executable Code. Constants (like your font data) often go to RAM, but don't need to...

Answer (score 0):

Nitro, Gerhard and datafiddler,

My problem was solved by a simple code optimization. I'm new to this Arduino world and so I was using a lot of unnecessary stuff.

I appreciated the help provided. Thanks!